# Submitting an applescript to xgrid using osascript

Tags: command-line, applescript, osascript

I'm trying to submit an applescript to an xgrid using the command line. But I've got something wrong with the formatting.

For example this doesn't work. I just get the help screen for xgrid in response.

```
xgrid -job submit osascript /Users/corey/xgrid/1.scpt
```

or

```
xgrid -job submit sips -s format jpeg /Users/corey/xgrid/RAW/tif/1.tif --out 1.jpg
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm having more success using: xgrid -h localhost -job submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `-h` tag with `localhost`. I didn't realize this was necessary as I was executing the command on the Controller computer.

```
xgrid -h localhost -job submit /Users/corey/xgrid/1.scpt
```

The commands are now being submitted to the Xgrid.